# Unique decomposition of a vector in finite-dim Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a **finite**-dimensional Hilbert space and $L$ and $L^{\perp}$ be a subspace and its orthogonal complement such that $$L\oplus L^{\perp}=\mathcal{H}$$.

Show that any vector $\boldsymbol {v}\in \mathcal{H}$ of norm $|\boldsymbol{v}|=1$ has a unique decomposition
$$ \boldsymbol{v} = a \boldsymbol{u}+b\boldsymbol{w} $$ for $\boldsymbol{u} \in L$  and $\boldsymbol{w} \in L^{\perp}$ and $|\boldsymbol{u}|=|\boldsymbol{w}|=1$ . **In particular, show that $a,b\geq 0 $ and real!**

Comment: This is false. Let $\mathcal{H}=\Bbb{C}^2$ with its usual inner product. Let $L$ and $L^\perp$ be the $x$ and $y$ axes. Then $v=(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)=2(1/2,0)+2(0,1/2)$.

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot to mention the normalization conditions on the vectors. All three vectors should have unit norm.

Comment: That mostly fixes things, but you'll also want $a,b \ge 0$ rather than $a,b > 0$, otherwise you can't express vectors lying completely in $L$ or $L^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is as follows.

**Existence:** Since $\mathcal{H} = L\oplus L^\perp$, $v=u'+w'$ for unique $u'\in L$ and $w'\in L^\perp$. Then if $u'=0$ or $w'=0$, we have $v=w'$ or $v=u'$, so $v=v+0$ or $v=0+v$ is a decomposition. Otherwise, we can write $$v= \|u'\| \frac{u'}{\|u'\|} + \|w'\|\frac{w'}{\|w'\|},$$
and this is a valid decomposition.

**Uniqueness:** Observe that we must have $au = \pi_L(v)$, $bw=\pi_{L^\perp}(v)$, and $a=\|au\|$, $b=\|bw\|$, so $a,b,u,w$ are uniquely determined (as long as $a,b\ne 0$, otherwise the corresponding unit vector is undetermined).

Comment: is there a typo in the displayed line? I do not see how this is in agreement with the unit normalization on all three vectors.

Comment: @Marsl, yes there was a typo. That should have been $\|w'\|$ in the denominator.